# Magento 2 : Change Display Form of Customizable Products

Tags: magento2, price, frontend, product-prices, customizable-options

The price of product with different design is shown below. I have kept the product price as zero and mentioned the price of variants like this. But in the front end its showing Suede+ 655.

[image]

I want it to be "Suede= Rs 655" or only "suede". How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add '=' instead of '+' before price,then you have to change in **Select.php**.

> Magento/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php

You have to replace '+' to '=' using :-

```
$priceStr = str_replace("+", "=", $priceStr);
```

Add **$priceStr = str_replace("+", "=", $priceStr);**  after

```
 foreach ($_option->getValues() as $_value) {
    $count++;
    $priceStr = $this->_formatPrice(
    [
        'is_percent' => $_value->getPriceType() == 'percent',
        'pricing_value' => $_value->getPrice($_value->getPriceType() == 'percent'),
    ]
 );

$priceStr = str_replace("+", "=", $priceStr);
```

I hope this will work for you.:)